# Segmentation fault on FD_ZERO() in socket programming with C using multi thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, asterisk

The same program is worked well when i build it alone. but when calling from a multi-threaded code it is not working.

**UPDATE:** I am trying to call this code from  a function ***mixmonitor_thread(void *obj)** located inside **Mix-monitor** module of **Asterisk** server (an IP based PBX).

Program stuck at **FD_ZERO()** function in socket programming in C. I am working in ***CentOS 6.5*** environment.
If I remove the FD_ZERO() then everything is working but select functions returning unpredictable result, may be because of lacking initialization of file descriptors with **FD_ZERO()**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <strings.h>

void my_function() 
{
    int flags = 0, error = 0, ret = 0;
    fd_set  rset, wset;

    socklen_t   len = sizeof(error);
    struct timeval  ts;

    ts.tv_sec = timeout;

    //clear out descriptor sets for select
    //add socket to the descriptor sets

    FD_ZERO(&rset);// ------------- HERE I AM GETTING THAT ISSUE  --------------

    FD_SET(sock, &rset);
    wset = rset;    //structure assignment ok

    //set socket nonblocking flag
    if( (flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0)) < 0)
        return -1;

    if(fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
        return -1;

    //initiate non-blocking connect
    if( (ret = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof (server_address)) < 0)
        if (errno != EINPROGRESS)
            return -1;

    if(ret == 0)    //then connect succeeded right away
        goto done;

    //we are waiting for connect to complete now
    if( (ret = select(sock + 1, &rset, &wset, NULL, (timeout) ? &ts : NULL)) < 0)
        return -1;
    if(ret == 0){   //we had a timeout
        errno = ETIMEDOUT;
        return -1;
    }

    //we had a positivite return so a descriptor is ready
    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &rset) || FD_ISSET(sock, &wset)){
        if(getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len) < 0)
            return -1;
    }else
        return -1;

    if(error){  //check if we had a socket error
        errno = error;
        return -1;
    }


}
```

While executing above program code, it stops at **FD_ZERO()** and shows segmentation fault. How do I fix it?

Comment: The code you posted has too many errors - it won't compile. Please post something that can actually builds.

Comment: Actually that is a huge file and above described steps are in different parts. so I have included the necessary code that is showing the basic functionality. Sorry to tell you that this code will not compile well, but it definitely helps you to understand the issue.

Comment: The code you posted won't compile, so it won't reproduce your problem either. In other words, it's not helpful to pinpoint your issue. [mcve] is the way to go.

Comment: Can you use a debugger? Tricky with threads, but definitely the bets way to find the problem

Comment: @Mawg I have debugged and didn't get any clue. debugger shows segmentation fault at  **0x00007f7c20d6d77d in pthread_getspecific () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0**

Comment: One possibility might be that you are overflowing your threads' stack.  You could try setting a larger stack-size (and/or allocating your fd_sets on the heap instead, just as a test) and see if that causes the fault to go away.

Comment: `if( (ret = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, 16)) < 0 )` What is `16`, and  how did you compute it ? And, what is `sa` (idem)?

Comment: *that is working well. don't consider that one.*  Ooof.  You're the one asking for help because you don't know what's going on.  Telling someone who likely knows a lot more about C than you do something like "that is working well. don't consider that one."  **when they are volunteering their time in order to try and help you** is just wrong.  @joop asked those questions for a reason - you'd be better of if you tried to figure out why those could be important points he made.

Comment: Also, wset is used before initilisation. And, EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK is not handled.

Comment: Seemingly irrational issues most often due to having invoked undefined behaviour (way long) before the "*seemingly irrational issues*" appear. Conclusion: winding your head around what's wrong with `FD_ZERO()` is most likely just looking at wrong place.